# ElasticSearch Cluster Replication

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an `Elasticsearch` cluster of 3 nodes. Each node can become a master and data node. My `Elasticsearch` settings are:

```
index.number_of_shards: 8
index.number_of_replicas: 2
gateway.recover_after_nodes: 2
gateway.recover_after_time: 5m
gateway.expected_nodes: 3
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 2
discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["host1", "host2:9200","host3:9200"]

My Cluster is up now and cluster health is green. But Shard allocation is like

Node1 - 0,1,2,3,4,6 where 6 is primary and other are replicas

Node2 - 5,6,7 all replicas

Node3 - 0,1,2,3,4,5,7 all primary
```

This structure shows only 1 replica copy of each shard split on nodes. But I mentioned 2 replicas in settings then it should show 2 replica copy of each shard.

Am I understanding it wrong or something is missing in settings.

Comment: Can you update your question with the output you get from `curl host1:9200/_cat/shards` ?

Comment: It says No handler found for uri [/_cat/shards] and method [GET] . Please let me know what information you required

Comment: Which version of ES do you have?

Comment: I have 0.90.5 version

Comment: :-) do please upgrade! That version is light years behind the latest and greatest. Also `index.number_of_replicas` is for new indices. The ones you already have need to be adjusted manually: `PUT /_all/_settings
{
  "index": {
    "number_of_replicas": 2
  }
}`.

Comment: Ok, that's pretty old, indeed, then you don't have the `_cat` API. Then you can use this: `curl -XGET 'http://host1:9200/_cluster/state'` instead

Comment: It gives all 3 cluster nodes info and shards info. Any specific info you required out of it because its not possible to past whole string

Comment: @Andrei - Thanks your suggestion worked for me to manually assign number of replicas for existing indexes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`index.number_of_replicas` from `elasticsearch.yml` is for new indices. The ones you already have need to be adjusted manually: `PUT /_all/_settings { "index": { "number_of_replicas": 2 } }`

Also, do please consider upgrading. ES is now at version 2.3.1, 0.90 is very old.